# Windows high availability file server - what to choose?

Tags: windows, cluster

Our "General use fileserver" need to be modified. We want:

1. Something like DFS namespases - always same path, even if fileserver changed.
2. "High availability", or better say "Fault tolerance" - connections to files survive even after one server down.

Planned clients:

1. Mostly Windows 8.1 and 10, small number of Windows 7 (will be upgraded in near future).
2. Network document scanner (Kyocera and HP), that can save files to network share.
3. Windows 2016 to host File Share Witness for other clusters.

What type of cluster to choose? DFSR? Continuous Availability?

AFAIK, general document scanners have problems with DFS namespases.
And what about FSW on DFSR?
Continuous Availability - everyone said that is for Hyper-V shares and SQL.

Your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with DFS namespaces. If clients have trouble, they can directly connect to a particular DFS namespace host and get a copy as a normal share.

For example, 3 servers, all with DFS Namespaces sharing

\\yourlan.lan\DFS\ScannedDocuments

- dfs1.yourlan.lan
- dfs2.yourlan.lan
- dfs3.yourlan.lan

Clients using document scanners find they are unable to scan...

Just set up a GPO to push the drive maps as the hosts themselves.

\\dfs1.yourlan.lan\ScannedDocuments